# Windows dump file

Tags: windows, disassembly

I open the dump file (.dmp) of a windows program written in c++ that crashed.  It is an access violation.  Why does the VS2015 disassembly display

```
32392D75  ?? ?? 
32392D76  ?? ?? 
32392D77  ?? ?? 
32392D78  ?? ??
```

Why doesn't it know what the instructions were? 
(I thought that was the point of a dump file)

Comment: It is called a "minidump".  The "mini" gets in the way when you don't do it right.  Like no point in including the code in the minidump when you can have it available on your own machine.  Not enough cues in the question to make the call, it is an "it doesn't work" question.

Comment: @HansPassant well the code got executed on my machine so it corresponds to some instruction, why isn't it available. I'm not trying to 'make it work' i just want to know why its not available.

Comment: Look at the address ranges of the loaded modules to find the one that's being executed at the point of interest. I don't know whether your debugger automatically resolves the information, once you point it at symbol information.